# Can't open file for writing

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to create a log file like so:

```
set logFilePath to (path to desktop folder as string) & "waiting.scpt.log" -- "/tmp/waiting.scpt.log" as text

-- set logFilePath to (path to "temp" from user domain as text) & "waiting.scpt.log"
try
    close access file logFilePath
on error err
    display dialog err
end try

set logFile to open for access logFilePath with write permission
```

I get a dialog saying `File file tlv-mp3u2:Users:idror:Desktop:waiting.scpt.log wasn’t open.` and then an error `error "File file tlv-mp3u2:Users:idror:Desktop:waiting.scpt.log is already open." number -49 from file "tlv-mp3u2:Users:idror:Desktop:waiting.scpt.log" to «class fsrf»`

I moved the file in question to the trash and ran the script again, same result

Also, what I really want is to open the file under /tmp, but if I try that I get "file access error" (-54)

I've given up finding answers in Google... so please help

Comment: CTRL-Click an AppleScript and check out the menu "Error Handlers"=>"Write Error to Log" - the code shows exactly how it's done.

Comment: @Zero: this is the best answer (concise and produces the complete solution). If you post as an answer, I'd accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CTRL-Click` an `AppleScript` and check out the menu `Error Handlers=>Write Error to Log` - the code shows exactly how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the sequence of your calls. The Applescript way to access files is always the same:

1. Open the file and store a file id pointing to the opened file
2. If needed get the index of the end of the file (needed to append text at the end)
3. Read/Write the content you want
4. Close the access to the file id

Your snippet looks like you try to close before opening the file. And if the opening works (should have been only once) the file remains open, because you don't close it. Maybe a restart helps or securly emptying the trash.

To do the log I recommend:

```
set logFilePath to (path to desktop folder as string) & "waiting.scpt.log"
doLog(logFilePath, "A new line to log!")

on doLog(pathToLogFile, logText)
    try
        -- open the file at logFilePath and store the file id
        set logFile to open for access pathToLogFile with write permission
        -- write the given text to the file, starting at the end of file to append
        write logText & return to logFile starting at (get eof logFile) + 1
        -- close the file asap
        close access logFile
    on error
        -- if something went wrong, finally try to close the file!
        try
            close access logFile
        end try
    end try
end doLog
```

Greetings, Michael / Hamburg

***Update after comment:***

I added a third parameter to the handler. To delete the content of a file you have to `set the eof to 0` as follows:

```
doLog(logFilePath, "A new line to log!", true)

on doLog(pathToLogFile, logText, appendLog)
    try
        -- open the file at logFilePath and store the file id
        set logFile to open for access pathToLogFile with write permission
        -- set the eof to 0, if appending is not wished
        if not appendLog then
            set eof logFile to 0
        end if
        -- write the given text to the file, starting at the end of file to append
        write logText & return to logFile starting at (get eof logFile) + 1
        -- close the file asap
        close access logFile
    on error
        -- if something went wrong, finally try to close the file!
        try
            close access logFile
        end try
    end try
end doLog
```

Comment: To delete the content of a file you have to set its eof to 0. I updated my answer!

Comment: what i ended up with is to declare the path as a global variable, then set eof to 0